# XML data in ntext to xml data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm a rookie when it comes to XML data.

I currently have a database with xml data being stored in a `ntext` column and this database appears to be taking up too much space. I'm trying to improve the way the data is stored, to reduce the overall size of the DB.

The way I see it, I have two options:

- `nvarchar(max)`
- `xml`

I will need to test the two options above by importing some data into those columns.

The problem I am having is, the XML data in the ntext column is currently stored as utf-8. In order for me to import it into the XML data type column, I will need to CAST/CONVERT the data to UTF-16?

Is this right?

Comment: Storing it as `XML` has two **major** benefits: (1) since it's stored as a native XML, you can do things like XQuery on top of it, and (2) since it's stored as `XML` it's stored in an optimized (tokenized) way, taking up **less space** than what the equivalent `nvarchar(max)` column would use up.

Comment: Thanks for that marc_s. Can you recommend any tutorials or articles to convert the utf8 xml data to utf16?

Comment: Your data cannot be UTF-8 - not inside SQL Server - since SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8 ....

Answer (score 5):

Storing you data as datatype `XML` has **two major benefits**:

1. since it's stored as a native XML, you can do things like XQuery on top of it
2. since it's stored as `XML` it's stored in an optimized (*tokenized*) way, taking up less space than what the equivalent `nvarchar(max)` column would use up.

To convert your existing `NTEXT` column: just do a `CAST` on it.

What results do you get frmo this:

```
SELECT 
   id, ntextColumn, CAST(ntextColumn AS XML)
FROM 
   dbo.YourTable
```

I am almost sure this will work - just like that. SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8 - so your data even in the `ntext` column is most likely not *really* stored as UTF-8 (it's already been converted to SQL Server's Unicode - UCS-2/UTF-16) so I don't see any issue with converting this to datatype `XML`, really.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far marc_s, really appreciate. I'm getting the following error message, when running the select statement. Msg 9402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding

Comment: Figured it out.

You can't use the above script against the data stored as "ntext". I had to create a new table and set the columns as NVARCHAR(MAX) and then IMPORT the data into the new table. The above script works against the data stored as NVARCHAR(MAX).

I was able to reduce the size of my DB, when importing the data into an XML table (xml data type).

Thanks for all of your help, very much appreciated.